# How do I use 'gsub' to make multiple substiuttions?

Tags: ruby, regex, gsub, substitution

I have a string that only contains one number on either side of `"-"`, like:

```
"1-3"
```

I want to get a result like

```
"01-03"
```

If the string had two numbers on one side of the dash like:

```
"1-10"
```

then I don't want to make any substitutions. I could do a `gsub` expression like

```
str.gsub!(/(^|[^\d]])\d[[:space:]]*\-[[:space:]]*\d([^\d]|$)/, '\1')
```

but I'm not clear how to do it if there are multiple (e.g. two) things to substitute.

Comment: Try [`str.gsub!(/\b(\d[[:space:]]*-[[:space:]]*)(\d)\b/, '0\10\2')`](http://ideone.com/RA3o51)

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew Don't forget the dash. Otherwise looks good and should be posted as an answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could probably get away with this:

```
def dashreplace(str)
  str.sub(/\b(\d)\-(\d)\b/) do |s|
    '%02d-%02d' % [ $1.to_i, $2.to_i ]
  end
end

dashreplace('1-2')
# => "01-02"
dashreplace('1-20')
# => "1-20"
dashreplace('99-1,2-3')
# => "99-1,02-03"
```

Answer (score 2):

Is there really a need to use regex here, at all? Seems like an over-complication to me. Assuming you know the string will be in the format: `<digits><hyphen><digits>`, you could do:

```
def pad_digits(string)
  left_digits, right_digits = string.split('-')
  if left_digits.length > 1 || right_digits.length > 1
    string
  else
    "%02d-%02d" % [left_digits, right_digits]
  end
end

pad_digits("1-3") # => "01-03"
pad_digits("1-10") # => "1-10"
```

Comment: If you can do it with regex, that is better. It is not over-complication in this case. Switching to arrays and back is more complicated than doing it within the domain of strings.

Comment: It depends on the wider context. If you need to perform the operation on a larger string, e.g `"1-2 foo 23-1 bar 0-99"` then I'd use a gsub/regex. If it's always on a simple string like this - but you might want to add more "complex" logic, such as varying the "digits length" or "split character" - then I'd go with my approach. To be honest, as the question currently stands, I'd consider any of the answers here acceptable.

Answer (score 1):

This is a variant of @TomLord's answer.

```
def pad_single_digits(str)
  str.size > 3 ? str : "0%d-0%d" % str.split('-')
end

pad_single_digits "1-3"  #=> "01-03"
pad_single_digits "1-10" #=> "1-10"
```

`"0%s-0%s"` also works.

Answer (score 0):

You can do:

```
def nums(s)
   rtr=s[/^(\d)(\D+)(\d)$/] ? '0%s%s0%s' % [$1,$2,$3] : s
end
```